# Forms Auth Cookie killed when new browser tab opened?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cookies, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an MVC4 site set up to authenticate using the Facebook SDK per following site:
http://ntotten.com/2012/12/19/facebook-authentication-with-the-facebook-c-sdk-and-asp-net-mvc-4/

My site lets the user launch new tabs(to an external site) via JavaScript (window.open)

My problem is, this seems to log out the user. So, user is logged into my site and stays logged in with no issues. Then, if they launch a new tab, and go back to the original tab, they are logged out.

Does the browser start a new session for each tab? And would with wipe our my auth cookie?

Comment: This should not happen and the easiest way to verify what is going on is to use an external http debugger, like Fiddler. Just inspect request and see what happens to cookies.

Comment: i would assume you are not saving your oath token, and using this when the page refreshes in order to keep login live.  OATH is cookie less, I.E  you must reload your auth token, and pass this to facebook, there is only one website for advice on facebook api, and that's facebook, you would then get a long life token and use this to create a userid in your system and link everything up